# ASP.Net RadioButtonList in UpldatePanel only select first item

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, radiobuttonlist

in my .aspx page: i have 3 Radiobuttonlist and all of them connected to Sqldatasource.

After displaying the data, each of them that I click goes to the first option and is selected.

For example, I choose the third option, but it goes to the first option !!

I did not write any code to the server !!! I do not know why this happened.

The code I wrote is exactly the same code below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" /></p>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-12 alefbasystemdotcom">
                    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Zusatzoptionen:</span>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbloptions" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="sdsoptions" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="price">
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsoptions" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HamoConStr %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM TypeExtraPay WHERE type='extra' AND cat=1">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 alefbasystemdotcom">
                    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Verarbeitung und Veredelung:</span>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblproccess" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="sdsproccess" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="price">
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsproccess" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HamoConStr %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM TypeExtraPay WHERE type='post' AND cat=1">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 alefbasystemdotcom">
                    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Angestrebter Liefertermin:</span>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbldeliverydate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="sdsdelivery" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="price">
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsdelivery" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HamoConStr %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM TypeExtraPay WHERE type='deliverydate' AND cat=1">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>
                <asp:Label Text="" ID="mylbl" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**Thank you for your help**

Comment: This is because Radiobuttonlist Databind again on the selectedIndex changes of click event. Do you want any specific item to be selected or to retain the previous selected one? Show us what you tried so far?

Comment: i have a label, all of radiobuttonlist them value is price, now i want every item in each radiobuttonlist selected i update price and show in label. in every SelectedIndexChanged radiobuttonlist i wrote : mylbl.Text = rblalefbasystemproccess.SelectedValue + rblalefbasystemoptions.SelectedValue + rblalefbasystemdeliverydate.SelectedValue